# YII2 Submitting form using ajax adds additional word in the URL

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

The current URL is `http://localhost/ncddp/backend/web/sp-bub/update?id=89`

In the form, there is a `select` tag with the values of a province. When a certain province is selected, It will submit using Jquery/Ajax to get the list of municipalities or cities.

here is the code...

```
$.post('sub-project/getcities',{'prov':prov_code}, function(data)
    {
       $('#tblspbub-city').html(data);
    }
```

but I get this response..

```
Remote Address:[::1]:80
Request URL:http://localhost/ncddp/backend/web/sp-bub/sub-project/getcities
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

I know this page is not found. Why did it submit to `http://localhost/ncddp/backend/web/sp-bub/sub-project/getcities` wherein it should be submitted to `http://localhost/ncddp/backend/web/sub-project/getcities`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you used relative path and you are here :

```
/ncddp/backend/web/sp-bub/
```

and sub-project/getcities will be subpath
Try absolute url like :

```
http://localhost/ncddp/backend/web/sub-project/getcities
```

or relative :

```
/ncddp/backend/web/sub-project/getcities
```